# Link to chrome://extensions page in non extension HTML

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am trying to link to chrome://extensions in a normal HTML page (of a non-extension). However clicking the link won't do anything:

```
<a href="chrome://extensions">chrome://extensions</a>
```

Right-clicking and opening in new tab just opens the about:blank page. How do I provide a working linking to the Chrome extensions page?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see if you open the console, this is completely impossible, for security reasons.